# gfortran operator overloading derived type and real()

Tags: fortran, operator-overloading, gfortran

I want to overload an operator (*) to perform vector-scalar multiplication in the following class:

```
  module vectorField_mod
    use constants_mod
    implicit none
    private

    public :: vectorField
    public :: allocateVectorField
    public :: delete

    type vectorField
      real(dpn),dimension(:,:,:),allocatable :: x,y,z
    end type

  interface operator (*)
    module procedure scalarMultiply
  end interface

  contains

    function scalarMultiply(f,g) result(q)
      implicit none
      type(vectorField),intent(in) :: f
      real(dpn),intent(in) :: g
      type(vectorField) :: q
      q%x = f%x * g
      q%y = f%y * g
      q%z = f%z * g
      q%sx = f%sx; q%sy = f%sy; q%sz = f%sz
    end function
    ...

  end module
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
  Error: Operands of binary numeric operator '*' at (1) are REAL(8)/TYPE(vectorfield)
```

I'm trying to implement this like:

```
 type(vectorField) :: a
 real(8) :: dt = 0.001

 call allocateVectorField(a,..)
 a = a*dt
```

Is this not a binary operation? Is there still a way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Summary:

1) The answer by @francescalus was necessary, but not sufficient to yield a successful compilation.

2) In addition, it turns out that the order of multiplication is important. That is a = a*dt works, but a = dt*a does not work (this was the problem I was having)

Here's an illustrative sample:

```
  module constants_mod
    integer,parameter :: dpn = selected_real_kind(14)
  end module

  module vectorField_mod
    use constants_mod
    implicit none
    private

    public :: vectorField
    public :: allocateX,allocateY,allocateZ
    public :: delete
    public :: operator(*)

    type vectorField
      integer,dimension(3) :: sx,sy,sz
      real(dpn),dimension(:,:,:),allocatable :: x,y,z
    end type

  interface delete
    module procedure deallocateVectorField
  end interface

  interface operator (*)
    module procedure scalarMultiply
  end interface

  contains

    function scalarMultiply(f,g) result(q)
      implicit none
      type(vectorField),intent(in) :: f
      real(dpn),intent(in) :: g
      type(vectorField) :: q
      q%x = f%x * g; q%y = f%y * g; q%z = f%z * g
      q%sx = f%sx; q%sy = f%sy; q%sz = f%sz
    end function

    subroutine allocateX(field,Nx,Ny,Nz)
      implicit none
      type(vectorField),intent(inout) :: field
      integer,intent(in) :: Nx,Ny,Nz
      if (allocated(field%x)) deallocate(field%x)
      allocate(field%x(Nx,Ny,Nz))
      field%sx = shape(field%x)
    end subroutine

    subroutine allocateY(field,Nx,Ny,Nz)
      implicit none
      type(vectorField),intent(inout) :: field
      integer,intent(in) :: Nx,Ny,Nz
      if (allocated(field%y)) deallocate(field%y)
      allocate(field%y(Nx,Ny,Nz))
      field%sy = shape(field%y)
    end subroutine

    subroutine allocateZ(field,Nx,Ny,Nz)
      implicit none
      type(vectorField),intent(inout) :: field
      integer,intent(in) :: Nx,Ny,Nz
      if (allocated(field%z)) deallocate(field%z)
      allocate(field%z(Nx,Ny,Nz))
      field%sz = shape(field%z)
    end subroutine

    subroutine deallocateVectorField(field)
      implicit none
      type(vectorField),intent(inout) :: field
      deallocate(field%x,field%y,field%z)
      field%sx = 0; field%sy = 0; field%sz = 0
    end subroutine

  end module

  program test
  use constants_mod
  use vectorField_mod
  implicit none
  type(vectorField) :: a,b
  integer :: N = 1
  real(dpn) :: dt = 0.1
  call allocateX(a,N,N,N)
  call allocateY(a,N,N,N)
  call allocateZ(a,N,N,N)

  call allocateX(b,N,N,N)
  call allocateY(b,N,N,N)
  call allocateZ(b,N,N,N)
  a%x = dble(1.0); a%y = dble(1.0); a%z = dble(1.0)
  b%x = dble(1.0); b%y = dble(1.0); b%z = dble(1.0)
  a = b
  a = a*dt ! compiles fine
  a = dt*a ! does not compile

  call delete(a)
  call delete(b)

  end program
```

Comment: `q%x = f%x * g` & `g` is ``vectorField`

Comment: That will work even when g is a scalar?.. Because that is the functionality I want

Comment: I've answered about the `private` nature of the defined operator, but could you check that you have the two operands the correct way around: the error message suggests your code has `dt*a`?  [Adding the `public` would be necessary either way.]

Comment: What's the value of `dpn`?

Comment: If you update the code fragment to show the order mismatch (see my previous comment) then I can make my answer more complete.  Also, if `dpn` is indeed `8` (which I assumed, but IanH was paying closer attention) clarifying that may be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default accessibility of the module is `private`.  This default applies also to the defined operator.

To make the operator identifier public (so that it can be used outside the module) use a `public` statement like:

```
public :: operator(*)
```

Comment: hmm. Good point, but that didn't seem to fix the problem, and I have an add operator that works, but doesn't seem to require the public statement

Comment: yeah, I'll post one in a few

Comment: This was a necessary part, but it turns out that the order resulted in the multiplication not working. I'll credit your answer and add a short summary to my question