# Errors #6259, #7715, #6355, #6303 in defining Derived Type specific assignment/operator procedures

Tags: fortran, assignment-operator, intel-fortran, derived-types

First of all, **Hi to everyone** ! Wish you all a good starting week :)

In enhancing (as well as simplifying some syntax) a previously developed Derived Type, I was (and some still) encountering some errors as in the title specification (**NOTE:** for details about full messages and their cause, please *read* the comment lines in the code below :) ).

Among them, the ones I was not understand the most (of the why I am getting them) are `error #6355: This binary operation is invalid for this data type.` for the `operator(==)`, and `error #6303: The assignment operation or the binary expression operation is invalid for the data types of the two operands.` for the `assignment(=)`.

Here is an example of source code (**NOTE:** in order to reproduce those errors, comment out the *type-bound procedure part*, and uncomment out the two interface bodies):

```fortr
module MPolicyMod
   implicit none
   private
   public :: MPolicy

   type, public :: MPolicy_t
      real(kind = 8) :: delta_fI_fct_
      real(kind = 8) :: delta_fJ_fct_
      real(kind = 8) :: interp_I_fct_
      real(kind = 8) :: interp_J_fct_
      integer :: id_pol_
   contains
      generic :: assignment(=) => MPolicy_fromPol_sub, MPolicy_fromID_sub
      procedure, private, pass :: MPolicy_fromID_sub, MPolicy_fromPol_sub
      generic :: operator(==) => MPolicy_isID
      procedure, pass, private :: MPolicy_isID
   end type MPolicy_t

   integer, public, parameter :: MPolicy_NULL  = 0
   integer, public, parameter :: MPolicy_DEF   = 1
   integer, public, parameter :: MPolicy_CONST = 2


   interface MPolicy_t
      module procedure MPolicy_constructor_integer
      module procedure MPolicy_constructor_real
      module procedure MPolicy_fromID
   end interface

   ! interface assignment(=)
   !   module procedure MPolicy_fromPol_sub
   !   module procedure MPolicy_fromID_sub
   ! end interface assignment(=)

   ! interface operator(==)
   !   module procedure MPolicy_isID
   ! end interface operator(==)


contains

   !> Main default constructor.
   function MPolicy_constructor_real(dfi, dfj, interpi, interpj, id) result(pol)
      real(kind = 8), intent(in) :: dfi, dfj, interpi, interpj
      integer, intent(in) :: id
      type(MPolicy_t) :: pol

      print *, ' Default constructor (as compiler)...'

      pol%delta_fI_fct_ = dfi
      pol%delta_fJ_fct_ = dfj
      pol%interp_I_fct_ = interpi
      pol%interp_J_fct_ = interpj
      pol%id_pol_       = id
   end function MPolicy_constructor_real


   function MPolicy_constructor_integer(dfi, dfj, interpi, interpj, id) result(pol)
      integer, intent(in) :: dfi, dfj, interpi, interpj, id
      type(MPolicy_t) :: pol

      print *, ' Default constructor (integer version)...'

      pol = MPolicy_t(real(dfi, 8), &
                        real(dfj, 8), &
                        real(interpi, 8), &
                        real(interpj, 8), id)
   end function


   function MPolicy_fromID(id) result(pol)
      integer, intent(in) :: id
      type(MPolicy_t)     :: pol

      print *, ' Constructor from ID...'

      select case (id)
         case (MPolicy_NULL)
            return
         case (MPolicy_DEF)
            pol = MPolicy_t(2, 2, 2, 2, MPolicy_DEF)
         case (MPolicy_CONST)
            pol = MPolicy_t(1, 1, 1, 1, MPolicy_CONST)
         case default
            block
               character(len=3) :: fmt

               write(fmt, '(i)'), id
               stop ' [ERROR] Unknow policy identifier "id"= '//fmt
            end block
      end select
   end function MPolicy_fromID


   subroutine MPolicy_fromPol_sub(lhs, rhs)
      class(MPolicy_t), intent(in) :: rhs
      class(MPolicy_t), intent(out) :: lhs

      lhs%delta_fI_fct_ = rhs%delta_fI_fct_
      lhs%delta_fJ_fct_ = rhs%delta_fJ_fct_
      lhs%interp_I_fct_ = rhs%interp_I_fct_
      lhs%interp_J_fct_ = rhs%interp_J_fct_
      lhs%id_pol_       = rhs%id_pol_
   end subroutine MPolicy_fromPol_sub


   subroutine MPolicy_fromID_sub(lhs, rhs)
      class(MPolicy_t), intent(out) :: lhs
      integer, intent(in)           :: rhs

      lhs = MPolicy_t(rhs)
   end subroutine MPolicy_fromID_sub


   function MPolicy(mpol) result(pol)
      integer :: mpol
      type(MPolicy_t) :: pol

      pol = MPolicy_t(mpol)
   end function MPolicy


   pure function MPolicy_isID(pol, id) result(isID)
      class(MPolicy_t), intent(in) :: pol
      integer, intent(in) :: id
      logical :: isID

      isID = pol%id_pol_ == id
   end function MPolicy_isID

end module
```

Example program:

```fortr
program test

   use MPolicyMod
   implicit none


   ! ! NOTE: generates
   ! !       error #6259: This array or function or substring is invalid in constant expressions.   [MPOLICYMOD^MPOLICY_FROMID]
   ! !       error #7715: Replacing invalid structure constructor by integer 1.   [<NULL_STRING>]
   ! type(MPolicy_t) :: pol = MPolicy_t(MPolicy_NULL)


   type(MPolicy_t) :: pol

   ! =========================================================================
   print *, pol
   pol = MPolicy_t(MPolicy_NULL)
   print *, pol

   ! ! NOTE: generates (without TYPE-BOUND specification)
   ! !       error #6355: This binary operation is invalid for this data type.
   print *, pol == MPolicy_NULL

   pol = MPolicy_t(1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
   print *, pol

   ! ! NOTE: generates (without TYPE-BOUND specification)
   ! !       error #6303: The assignment operation or the binary expression operation is invalid for the data types of the two operands.
   pol = MPolicy_DEF
   print *, pol
end program test
```

Then, after reading through the [ISO Fortran Standard 2003 Draft document](https://wg5-fortran.org/N1601-N1650/N1601.pdf), at Section 4.5.4 *Type-bound procedures*, Rule **R452** states that we could specify `assignment(=)` as a *generic-spec*, in a *generic-binding* type of *proc-binding-stmt*. There I realised I was missing the *type-bound specifications* for those operator/assignment procedures.

Why, then, only the interface body was not enough to make it work?

After this, I also wonder why the initialisation statement `type(MPolicy_t) :: pol = MPolicy_t(MPolicy_NULL)` generates errors #6259 and #7715.

For that, I still didn't search by my own. But if you come with an asnwer before I might find (hopefully) an explanation, it's always good to have **constructive as well as polite discussions** with You all.

I now go back to my searching. Have a nice day :)

Comment: One cannot implement `assignment(=)` using a function.

Comment: @francescalus In fact they're not functions ;)

Comment: @francescalus wait, you mean for the errors at `type(MPolicy_t) :: pol = MPolicy_t(MPolicy_NULL)` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's true. But perhaps goes to show that your example could do with being simplified a little bit (see [mre]) as there's quite a lot going on which at first glance is confusing. (Anyone actually answering this question is going to spend much more time glancing over than I did, but can't hurt to make their life a bit easier too, if possible.)

Comment: Don't worry about `type(MPolicy_t) :: pol = MPolicy_t(MPolicy_NULL)`: initialization uses intrinsic assignment only, never defined assignment. Actually, do worry about it, as I see you also ask about that. Yes: that's not allowed, but not allowed for completely different reasons (not being a constant expression).

Comment: @francescalus, referring to the before-last comment, yeah, I know and thought about it. The real code is actually way longer than that, still I tried not to cut it too much but keeping it *as complete as possible* for readers which might "learn" something more out of these discussions. Also because of all the related questions. But if needed I cut it :)

Comment: Hmm, the answer about the operator/assignment could really be quite boring: `private`. If those two bits work without `private` then we've probably got a duplicate for you.

Comment: Referring to the last comment instead, so it's not a *programming error* per-se. Just the compiler doesn't actually do what we'd like it to do, is it? For sake of completeness, it does not also work with `type(MPolicy_t) :: pol = MPolicy_NULL`, rejecting `error #6303`. However, here it's a bit tricky then. Even though it looks like a *constant expressions* (`MPolicy_NULL` is a compile time constant), it rejects it since it should call a Defined Assignment? But the error message it's a bit misleading then..

Comment: "Hmm, the answer about the operator/assignment could really be quite boring: `private`. If those two bits work without `private` then we've probably got a duplicate for you."  Could you provide it, so that I might understand better what you mean? :)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28161942/3157076) for example.

Comment: @francescalus Oook, now I get it, what a stupid. The actual methods being private was not providing any known interface to the outside. Then, now some more questions :D. Why the *type-bound procedures* approach did not show the problem. Does the compiler provide the interface with the DT specification itself? Lastly, among the two approaches, which one should be **preferred** in terms of Modern Fortran Standard Compliant (given there's any intrinsic difference in implementation)? Thanks :))

Comment: Bindings of a type have the [same accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44253708/3157076) as the type itself.